# Dart language, How to extract specific part from a string

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to extract from the full String this part:

```
<a href=\"https://example.com/members/will/\">Will</a>
```

full String:

```
"<a href=\"https://example.com/members/will/\">Will</a> posted an update in the group <a href=\"https://example.com/groups/testing/\">Testing</a>"
```

Another example

```
    <a href=\"https://example.com/members/longerName/\">longerName</a>
```

full String:

```
"<a href=\"https://example.com/members/longerName/\">longerName</a> posted an update in the group <a href=\"https://example.com/groups/testing/\">Testing</a>"
```

any help please

Comment: Use a Regular Expression.

Comment: du you have an example please?

Comment: Weren't any questions on SO that could resolve this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head, this could work.

**Regex**

`<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)</a>`

**Dart**

```
final myString = "<a href=\"https://example.com/members/will/\">Will</a> bla bla bla";
final regexp = RegExp(r'<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)</a>'); 

// final match = regexp.firstMatch(myString);
// final link = match.group(0);

Iterable matches = regexp.allMatches(myString);
matches.forEach((match) {
  print(myString.substring(match.start, match.end));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This could work:

```
String str = "<a href=\"https://example.com/members/will/\">Will</a> posted an update in the group <a 
href=\"https://example.com/groups/testing/\">Testing</a>";

String result = str.split("</a>")[0] + "</a>";
```

Comment: this works too, good answer thank you, im sorry since i cant mark the 2 answers correct, i can only confirm in comments that your answer works GOOD